# finding next/previous tv show from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I've become rather stuck with a situation I have. I have a database with fields id, showid, season, episode and some other arbitrary data. I have a php page to display information about episodes of shows which works by having the id as a get variable. What I wish to achieve is to have a link to the next episode and previous episode of this tv program however the shows aren't necessarily in order and so simply incrementing or decrementing the id will not help.
So I would fetch the episodes and store then in `$rows` with the following `MySQL` query:

`SELECT id FROM episodes WHERE showid = $id ORDER BY season, episode;`

Now without having to loop through the array (which could be rather large for some shows) is there an easy way for me to find the next and previous episode? I'm sure there is I just can't think of it.

**Edit:**
I have been thinking about this myself and nothing all that helpful has come through yet (although thanks for the help, its much appreciated). What I have thought of is to make a query to see if a higher episode exists of the same season, if not make another query to find the lowest episode of then next lowest season - or something along those lines - and then repeat for previous. What do you think?

**Edit 2:**
I thought I would post my final code for future reference.
Here I find the id's of the nex and previous shows (if they exist).

Find the next episode:

```
try {
    // First check for a show of the same season but the next lowest episode number
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM episodes WHERE showid = :show AND season = :s AND episode > :e ORDER BY episode LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->execute($pars);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if(count($rows) > 0) { // If there is one this is our next id
        $nextid = $rows[0]['id'];
    } else {
        // Otherwise check for an episode of a higher season number
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM episodes WHERE showid = :show AND season > :s ORDER BY season, episode LIMIT 1;");
        $stmt->execute($pars);
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if(count($rows) > 0) { // If there is one this is our next id.
            $nextid = $rows[0]['id'];
        } // Otherwise no next id is set and so no next link will be created.
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Find the previous episode:

```
try {
    // First check for an episode in same season of the next highest episode number.
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM episodes WHERE showid = :show AND season = :s AND episode < :e ORDER BY episode DESC LIMIT 1;");
    $stmt->execute($pars);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if(count($rows) > 0) { // If one is found then this is our prev id.
        $previd = $rows[0]['id'];
    } else {
        // Otherwise check for an episode of a lower season number.
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM episodes WHERE showid = :show AND season < :s ORDER BY season DESC, episode DESC LIMIT 1;");
        $stmt->execute($pars);
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        if(count($rows) > 0) { // If there is one this is our prev id.
            $previd = $rows[0]['id'];
        } // Otherwise no prev id is set and so no prev link will be created.
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Then I have the following links:

```
if($previd) echo "<a href=\"/tv/view/" . $previd . "/\">Previous Episode</a>";
if($nextid) echo "<a href=\"/tv/view/" . $nextid . "/\">Next Episode</a>";
```

Comment: Isn't `episode` a consecutive numbering?

Comment: It could be more user-friendly to use a example.com/show/season/episode URL structure, which would also make it easy to link to the next/previous episodes.

Comment: I already have the showid, episode and season on hand after I made the query to get information to output to the page and so this wouldn't actually be all that beneficial other than aesthetics.

Comment: If you fetch all the show's episodes from the database at once, you're going to have to loop through them in one way or another. It's that, or specifically fetching the current, previous and next episodes.

Comment: well that's what i did in the end, separate queries for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not doing it like a paginator of a table, but showing only one entry your actual page.
You can do this by expading your query like this:

```
SELECT id FROM episodes WHERE showid = $id ORDER BY season, episode LIMIT 0,1;
```

Where the 0 is the offset. That means the starting record, which you have to increment.
Here as an example:

```
SELECT id FROM episodes WHERE showid = $id ORDER BY season, episode LIMIT $page,1;
```

Then you only have to pass the page of the actual shown episode as GET parameter "?page=0" in you URL. Previous episode is page - 1 and next is page + 1.

Only pitfall is that you have to check for fist and las episode. To know when previous or next is not possible.

Comment: I do like this technique and I have seen this done in other similar examples on the web. This is probably the best method I've seen anyway

Answer (score 0):

If the ids aren't in any particular order, then you'll have to basically scan the table for where you currently are, and then use the last fetched and about-to-fetch records as your prev/next episodes, e.g.

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$previous_episode = $row['id']; // prime the system
do {
   if ($row['id'] == $id_of_current_episode) {
       $next_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
       $next_episode = $row['id'];
       break;
   }
} while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```

This won't handle the case where you're already at the last episode gracefully, but should get you started.

Comment: Really? mysql_? REALLY?

Comment: why not?  I don't generally go in for the inigo montoya mentality around here where mysql is concerned. "hello, you have used a deprecated function. prepare to die". they're handy for quick/dirty examples.

Comment: Hello, my name is the mysql_ killer. You used a deprecated function. Prepare to die.

Comment: I agree, I've gotten into the habbit these days of using PDO for absolutely everything, even if all the variables are integers I have generated myself I simply always use it

Comment: Definitely PDO (or at least mysqli) is the way to go now, but it's hard to toss off a quick oneliner in those.

Comment: I think this example would also work if it uses `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Answer (score 0):

I posted 3 times in this thread my bad, but if your episodes and IDs aren't ordered then there's no way to do this as far as I know

Fix your IDs

Comment: The ID's arent in order because there are times when I have to add in another episode to a show at a later date, after I have added episodes from other shows

Comment: i think the best thing you can do is make a table for every show

Comment: I debated this in the first place but thought it would end up messy after adding lots of shows, then again having one big table is also very messy. Regardless, what I have works and so I'm not complaining